# No Facebook-Likes after server crash

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

After the server had crashed, the affected url was not available a few days. 
Now the article under the old url is back online, but the 1900 facebook likes are gone. The url is absolutely correct.

What can I do to show the likes again for this article?